# Ionic cordova camera multiple photos

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using

```
this._camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
   this.takePicture();
   
});
```

But I want to leave it on user how many photo want to capture, but with this code it is not showing camera exit option

On button click - opening camera

```
<ion-icon color="primary" name="camera" tappable (click)="takePicture()" size="large"></ion-icon> 

takePicture() {
let options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this._camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this._camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this._camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  correctOrientation: true,
  sourceType: this._camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
  //allowEdit: true,
  targetWidth: window.screen.width,
  targetHeight: window.screen.height - 50,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true
}
this._camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

  //this.takePicture(); used to open camera but I want a Ok button after photo click user can exit/ stop camera. Here I donot have any option to close/ stop camera only back of device.

  this.croppedImagepath = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;

  this.photos.push({ imagePath: imageData, croppedImagepath: this.croppedImagepath });

});
```

}

Hope I am clear, please let me know if need other information.

Comment: I didn't get it. Do you want the camera still remain open even if the user takes the picture?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please Add more Details.

Comment: Please post complete code not just fragments. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: When I am using this.takePicture(); in success, no option to quit or stop camera and use only some clicked file,  eg - if I clicked 5 pictures, now want to save/ use only those 5 and stop camera. How can I do?